# Stubbing WebSocket in JavaScript with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, websocket, jasmine, stub

I try to test if `onmessage` is a proper function.

Here is a test:

```
  describe(".init(address, window)", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      address = 'ws://test.address';
      window = {};
      e = {
        data: {}
      }
      spyOn(window, 'WebSocket').and.returnValue(function() {return {onmessage: null}});
      spyOn(subject, 'handleMessage');
    });

    it("should create a WebSocket client which connects to the given address", function() {
      subject.init(address, window);
      expect(window.WebSocket).toHaveBeenCalledWith(address);
    });

    it("should have onmessage method overriden with a function which handles message", function() {
      ws = subject.init(address, window);
      alert(JSON.stringify(ws));
      ws.onmessage(e);
      expect(subject.handleMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(e.data);
    });
  });
```

Here is the implementation:

```
FL.init = function(address, window) {
  if ('WebSocket' in window) {
    var ws = new WebSocket(address);
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
      this.handleMessage(e.data);
    };
    return ws;
  }
};
```

The first test passes. In the second, `ws` is `undefined`. Why is that? I tried in a console `new function() {return {onmessage: null}}` and it looks it should be ok.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not completely sure that I figured out how your code is supposed to behave, but if you need to spy on `WebSocket` constructor and stub `.send` method to mock some incoming messages, here is how to achieve it.

To spy on `WebSocket` you will need to call `.and.callThrough` rather than `returnValue`. However it result with complains about lack of `new` keyword (as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548329/spy-and-callthrough-native-websocket-constructor-with-jasmine%20here)), so you need to fake the constructor:

```
var realWS = WebSocket;
var WebSocketSpy = spyOn(window, "WebSocket").and.callFake(function(url,protocols){
  return new realWS(url,protocols);
});
```

To make a spy for incoming messages you can simply do

```
var onmessageCallbackSpy = jasmine.createSpy('onmessageCallback');
```

You can also spy on `.send` method, and provide some mocked responses with:

```
var sendSpy = spyOn(WebSocket.prototype, "send").and.callFake(function(outMsg){
  // process/check outgoing message
  // setTimeout, or call it immediately
  this.onmessage("mock message goes here");
});
```

But make sure to use `WebSocket.prototype`, before you replace it with `WebSocketSpy`.

So full working example, should look like this:

```
it("should spy and callFake WebSocket constructor, and stub prototype methods", function (done) {
    var realWS= WebSocket;  
    var sendSpy = spyOn(WebSocket.prototype, "send").and.callFake(function(outMsg){
      if(outMsg == "outgoing message"){
        this.onmessage("incoming mocked message goes here");
      }
    });  
    // var messageSpy = spyOn(WebSocket.prototype, "onmessage");//.and.returnValue("mock message goes here");      
    var WSSpy = spyOn(window, "WebSocket").and.callFake(function(url,protocols){
      return new realWS(url,protocols);
    }); 
    var onmessageCallbackSpy = jasmine.createSpy('onmessageCallback');       

    // Your code
    // (function init(url, onmessageCallbackSpy){
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://some/where");
        ws.onmessage = onmessageCallbackSpy;
        // code that results with receiving a message
        // or mocked send, that calls `.onmessage` immediately
        ws.send("outgoing message");
    // })();    

    expect(WSSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("ws://some/where");
    expect(onmessageCallbackSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("mock message goes here");
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across it trying to mock a websocket for jasmine tests. Here is a solution that uses quite an extensive mock window.WebSocket.

```
var socketMock;
var windowMock;
var address = 'ws://test.address';

describe(".init(address, window)", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    var WebSocket = jasmine.createSpy();
    WebSocket.and.callFake(function (url) {
      socketMock = {
        url: url,
        readyState: WebSocket.CONNECTING,
        send: jasmine.createSpy(),
        close: jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSING;
        }),

        // methods to mock the internal behaviour of the real WebSocket
        _open: function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.OPEN;
          socketMock.onopen && socketMock.onopen();
        },
        _message: function (msg) {
          socketMock.onmessage && socketMock.onmessage({data: msg});
        },
        _error: function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSED;
          socketMock.onerror && socketMock.onerror();
        },
        _close: function () {
          socketMock.readyState = WebSocket.CLOSED;
          socketMock.onclose && socketMock.onclose();
        }
      };
      return socketMock;
    });
    WebSocket.CONNECTING = 0;
    WebSocket.OPEN = 1;
    WebSocket.CLOSING = 2;
    WebSocket.CLOSED = 3;

    windowMock = {
      WebSocket: WebSocket
    };
    spyOn(subject, 'handleMessage');
  });

  it("should create a WebSocket client which connects to the given address", function() {
    subject.init(address, windowMock);
    expect(windowMock.WebSocket).toHaveBeenCalledWith(address);
  });

  it("should have onmessage method overriden with a function which handles message", function() {
    var message = 'hello socket';
    subject.init(address, window);

    // pretend the socket connected (optional)
    socketMock._open();

    // pretend the socket got a message
    socketMock._message(message)

    expect(subject.handleMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(message);
  });
});
```