# Spy and callThrough native WebSocket constructor with Jasmine

Tags: websocket, jasmine

I'm trying to spy on native `WebSocket` constructor, so I wrote:

```
it("should spy and call through WebSocket constructor", function (done) {
  var WSspy = spyOn(window, "WebSocket").and.callThrough();

  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://some/where");

  expect(WSspy).to.toHaveBeenCalledWith("ws://some/where");
});
```

but it results in error:

```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

How should I `callThrough` such constructor?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround with `callFake`:

```
it("should spy and callFake WebSocket constructor", function (done) {
  var realWS = WebSocket;  
  var WSSpy = spyOn(window, "WebSocket").and.callFake(function(url,protocols){
    return new realWS(url,protocols);
  });        

  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://some/where");

  expect(WSSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("ws://some/where");
  done();
});
```

It works quite fine, but it overwrites the `WebSocket.prototype` so make sure you use it or save the reference before creating the spy, like

```
var realWS = WebSocket;  
var messageSpy = spyOn(WebSocket.prototype, "close").and.callThrough();      
var WSSpy = spyOn(window, "WebSocket").and.callFake(function(url,protocols){
  return new realWS(url,protocols);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 
"it overwrites the `WebSocket.prototype` so make sure you use id before creating the spy"

I don't see any reference to an id in the example you posted afterwards?

Comment: Thanks ~id~it was a typo. Is it better now?

Comment: Ah yeah I see now, sorry if it seemed nit picky, I was genuinely confused.  Thanks.