# How do I define and receive data from multiple WebSockets in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, sockets, websocket

I have the following code snippet which I need to extend to define multiple WebSockets and I am clueless as to how do I go about it:

```
    var registerWebSocketHandlers = function(webSocket) {
    webSocket.onclose = function(){
        setTimeout(service.reopen, reconnectTimeout *= 2);
    };

    webSocket.onopen = function(e) {
        icc.publish('webSocket.reconnect');
        reconnectTimeout = defaultReconnectTimeout; //reset this
        deferredSend();
    };

    webSocket.onerror = function(e) {
        throw new Error("[WebSocket] An error occured " + e);
    };
    }

    var openConnection = function() {
    connectionWasOpenBefore = true;
    webSocket = new $window.WebSocket(xyz);
    webSocket.id = uniqid();
    registerWebSocketHandlers(webSocket);
    };

    var uniqid = function() {
    return (new Date().getTime()).toString(16);
    }

    service.setMessageEventHandler = function(cb) {
    webSocket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        if(msg.data.indexOf('Status: connected') === 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(msg.data);
        cb(jsonObj);
    };
};
```

How do I twist the code to suit the needs of multiple WebSockets and attaching the appropriate callback to it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the multiton pattern.

```
var socketFactory = module.factory('SocketFactory', function($rootScope){
    var factory = {};
    var instances = {};

    factory.getInstance = function(name, config){
        if(!(name in instances)){
            instances[name] = createNewWebSocketInstance(name, config);
        }
        return instances[name];
    };

    var createNewWebSocketInstance = function(name, config){
        var webSocket = new $window.WebSocket(config.address);
        webSocket.id = uniqid();
        registerWebSocketHandlers(webSocket, name, config.handlers); //etc.
        return webSocket;
    };

    var registerWebSocketHandlers = function(webSocket, name, handlers){
        webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
            $rootScope.$emit('SocketMessageReceived_' + name, event.data);
        };
        //etc...
    };

    return factory;
});
```

This will separate your different websockets by name. Use getInstance('whatever') to get a websocket labelled as 'whatever'.

```
var firstConfig = {url: '*****', username: '****', password: '****', etc: '****'};
// You only need to pass in the config the first time.
var firstWebSocket = SocketFactory.getInstance('firstSocket', firstConfig);
var secondConfig = {url: '####', username: '####', password: '####', etc: '####'};
var secondWebSocket = SocketFactory.getInstance('secondSocket', secondConfig);
```

Next, from any other area you can access the configured websockets by their instance names.

```
var firstWebSocket = SocketFactory.getInstance('firstSocket');
// It would probably be a good idea to add this listener in the SocketFactory instead and broadcast an event when there's a message so multiple listeners can respond to it.
firstWebSocket.onmessage = function(){...};
var secondWebSocket = SocketFactory.getInstance('secondSocket');
secondWebSocket.onmessage = function(){...};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but could you throw some light on how will I distinguish between the messages coming from different sockets and how do I kickstart with the instance thing?

Comment: I edited my answer to add some initialization example. This is starting code. You'll probably want to iterate on this to improve it.

Comment: You can differentiate between the different websockets in a number of ways: a) Use a different listener function for each. b) Use a different listener function that adds some differentiating information (the instance name) before passing the message along to the rest of the app. c) Use events, and add the instance name as an extra property with the event data.

Comment: Thanks sir :) I had figured that out..but your version looks more readable and precise..I still have vague thoughts about calling the appropriate handler for the socket.. I mean is it possible to achieve that through multiple sockets ?? Could you elaborate more on this line of yours ?  **registerWebSocketHandlers(webSocket, config.handlers);** I mean the config.handlers arguments definition..my version shows registerWebSocketHandler with just one param and then directly we have setMessageEventHandler which is called from the different service classes.

Comment: I'm sure what you need to do is possible. It depends on how you want it to work in the end. Here's what I'd do: In the SocketFactory, add an onmessage handler that just re-broadcasts the message with the instance name (`webSocket.onmessage = function(event){ $rootScope.$emit('socketMessageReceived_' + instanceName, event.data); }`). Then from anywhere in the app, listen to the rootScope event 'socketMessageReceived_firstSocket'.

Comment: actually, you can probably just forget about the `config.handlers` part completely. It's probably not necessary at all.

Comment: Yes, that looks great to me.. Let me give it a try.. Also, is it a good idea to register web socket handler at the time of the creation of the web socket ? And are you aware of any testing tool where I can test this ??

Comment: If you choose to do with events as I would then yes, register every handler as soon as the websocket is created. It can be done at that time, and there's no benefit to doing it later.
I don't know about a testing tool, but you ought to be able to write some unit tests for it pretty easily. Just mock the WebSocket and the rest should be straightforward. I use jasmine and karma for unit tests.

Comment: Could you provide some tips on testing this ? I am looking to emulate multiple endpoints which sends in data continously.

Comment: what kind of tips are you looking for?
`it('should emulate multiple endpoints', function(){
/*1: Create a mock WebSocket so you can manually call the callback methods in the test. 2: Add event listeners to the two websockets you'll create. 3: Spy on those listeners. 4: Use your mock to execute the 'onmessage' function (repeat for other callbacks). 5: Ensure the correct spies have been called with the corresponding test messages*/
})`

Comment: I mean I absolutely have no clue how to go about that..could you please provide a code snippet for one or two ??

Comment: Sorry dude, that's a bit more than I'm willing to do. I'm ok with solving a few problems here and there when people get stuck, but teaching someone how to unit test would take a lot of time, and a google search would give you tutorials people have already written.

Comment: I don't expect you to teach me unit testing, i just wanted to know the code snippet of mocking websocket in jasmine/karma. I looked up on the internet but most of the snippets use SockJs which isn't suitable for my requirement. Also, I am just a starter with the front end so apologies for my stupid questions.

Comment: Oh ok, that's a less general, more manageable question. Here's a SO question with a good answer to that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28550855/4518468

That takes you through everything needed to mock a WebSocket with jasmine. Technically this author's not creating a full mock. Instead he's "spying" on just the functions of interest. The 1st answer (with 0 points) shows what a full mock would look like, but his code is incomplete and it's probably more than you need to do anyway.