# Unit test for web socket server needs web page open in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a unit test written in mocha for node.js that tests a web socket connection and parsing that is done on the client.  My problem is that I need to have the client web page open to communicate with the web socket server.  Is there any way to simulate that within node.js?

My unit test operates like follows:

1) A web socket starts up and waits for a client to connect.

2) Opens client at a specific URL (currently missing, using a web browser set to the URL I am testing). The client connects to the web socket and tries over and over if it is not available.

3) Once the client connects to the web socket it sends out json to test logic in the client.

4) The client sends back json that is validated at the web socket and the test passes if the web socket receives an appropriate response.

Right now everything works great except that I have to open a browser to the test URL. I would like to be able to run the test without opening a browser.

Comment: Can it be stubbed or mocked? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151954/stubbing-websocket-in-javascript-with-jasmine) help, or may [this](https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket)?

Comment: I am looking for something to mock a client.  I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/01/28/testing-socketio-with-mocha-should-and-socketio-client/) helps?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [selenium-webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). It works perfectly when you need to open an instance of chrome.  It also allows you to set text fields and send key presses if you need to log into a form or something like that.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var monitor = {width: 1920, height : 1200};
var host = "http://localhost:8000/";
var _webBrowser = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
_webBrowser.manage().window().setPosition(0, 0);
_webBrowser.manage().window().setSize(monitor.width / 2, monitor.height);
_webBrowser.get(host);
```